# How can I make it so that J grasp finds the main method in this blackjack game?

Tags: java

I am developing a blackjack game using java but after i got done (or almost done) writing the whole program J grasp says "No main methods, applets or MIDlets found in file." The code is below. How do i make J Grasp find the main method. If you notice any other thing that will keep the code from running, how would I fix those other things as well.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Blackjack{

private int points;
private int limit;
private Scanner scan;
private boolean firstTime;
private String response;
private int outcomeOfRoll;


//*******reminder to myself: the word void in the next line of code could be incorrect**********
public Blackjack(){
   scan = new Scanner (System.in);
}


public void displayPoints(){
System.out.print("Your points: " + points + "/" + limit);
}

public void startGame () {
System.out.print("Enter point limit");
limit=scan.nextInt();
displayPoints();

}



public void Roll (){
Random randomRoll = new Random();
int outcomeOfRoll = randomRoll.nextInt(6)+1;
System.out.print("You rolled a " + outcomeOfRoll);
}


public String askUser (boolean firstTime){
String response = null;
if (firstTime== true){
System.out.print("Start playing?");
response = scan.next();
return response;
}
else {
System.out.print("Keep playing?");
response = scan.next();}
return response;
}


public void displayResult(){
if (points==limit)
System.out.print("Blackjack!");
else if (points>limit)
System.out.print("Bust!");
else if (points<limit)
System.out.print("Stand at " + points + " points!");
}

public void play(){
boolean gameOver = false;
startGame();
askUser(firstTime);

while(response.equals("yes") && gameOver==false){

points = points + outcomeOfRoll;

displayPoints();

if (points>=limit) 
gameOver=true;

askUser(firstTime);

displayResult();
}
}

public void main(){
play();
}

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you need to have a method named main in at least one class and it has to be public static void and takes an array of String as a parameter.

Main method in Java looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

just modify your main method to match it's signature exactly

for more information I suggest you to read [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN)